# Export HTML table to Excel using ASP.NET with multiple work sheets

Tags: asp.net, html, export-to-excel

I have two different html tables with me.

Now I want to export these two html table to single excel sheet with two different sheets (i.e work sheet). For example, table 1 will be one sheet and table 2 will be in another sheet. But both these sheets will be present in one Excel file only.

I am not using any grid view or data view.

I don't want to save the Excel file on server.

Answer (score 0):

Below method is the simple solution to export all the content in html to excel:

```
Response.Clear();     
Response.Buffer = true;     
Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition","attachment;filename="+DateTime.
Now.ToString("yyyyMMdd")+".xls");           
Response.ContentEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;   
Response.ContentType = ""application/ms-excel";;   
this.EnableViewState = false;
```

you need to export different html tables, you can first save the html table in two excel files and then, use the merge all the data into one excel with different sheets.

you can see details here:
[Export Data to Excel for ASP.NET](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/164582/8-Solutions-to-Export-Data-to-Excel-for-ASP-NET)